# 'Build up Your chess' but a level lower

Tags: books, training

I've bought first tome of 'Build up Your chess' but it is too difficult for me. I am looking for the comprehensive self-study book exactly like 'Build up...' but for a little weaker player.

Comment: What's your rating?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any books that follow the format that Yusupov uses in his series.

*The Soviet Chess Primer* by Ilya Maizelis, and *Journey to the Chess Kingdom* by Averbakh and Beilin are both good initial books. *The Complete Idiot's Guide to Chess* by Patrick Wolff is also a nice book.

There are also series of books, such as Yasser Seirawan's *Winning Chess ...* series, and Lev Alburt's books.